# Confidence Intervals for the Mean of the Poisson Distribution 9-19 methods coded as an R package

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I've trawled the internet looking for R packages to compute the confidence intervals for the mean of a Poisson distribution using the different methods cited by Patil and Kulkarni in their papaer "comparison of confidence intervals for the Poisson mean: some new aspects", REVSTAT vol. 10, no. 2, June 2012, pp 211-227.

I have found in the R package, 'exactci', the routine poisson.exact, which gives a few methods. In the epitools R package there is pois.exact, pois.daly, pois.yar, and pois.approx.

In the 'stats' R package there is poisson.test which uses the Clopper Pearson method for the confience interval of the mean.

But in addition to these I was looking for those methods where the confidence interval is narrower, i.e. in a similar vein to the  methods outlined for interval estimation of binomial proportions, as laid out in the paper by Agresti and Coull, 'Approxiamte is better than "Exact" for Interval Estimation of binomial proportions' the Amer. Stat. May 1998, vol. 52, no.2 pp 119-126.

And on reading similar papers to the above on the Poisson distribution it was clear that for a good survey of confidence intervals, the score method and its variants should be included. It is these methods that do not appear to have been included in any R packages yet ? The closest I found was an R Package on Tolerance Intervals, ('Tolerance'). I don't claim to be totally clear on the distinction between CI and TI, but I think the latter guarantees something (e.g. measured length of a part) will lie in that interval to a given level of probability, but with the CI we are making a statement that the mean will lie in an interval to a given level of probablity.

Is there an R package that does the CI calculation for the Poisson Distribution using these approximate methods (but not the normal dist. approx.) ?

Thanks